# Inserting Large volume of data in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005

We have a application (written in c#) to store live stock market price in the database (SQL Server 2005). It insert about 1 Million record in a single day. Now we are adding some more segment of market into it and the no of records would be double (2 Millions/day).

Currently the average record insertion per second is about 50, maximum is 450 and minimum is 0.

To check certain conditions i have used service broker (asynchronous trigger) on my price table. It is running fine at this time(about 35% CPU utilization).

Now i am planning to create **a in memory dataset**  of current stock price. we would like to do some simple calculations.

Currently i am using xml batch insertion method. (OPENXML in Storred Proc)

I want to know different views of members on this.

Please provide your way of dealing with such situation.

Comment: what is your question? Are you asking for a viable architecture?

Comment: "We would have some simple calculations " Should that read, we would like to do some simple calculations?

Why take shedloads of data out of the database, into a memory dataset to perform simple calculations, SQL is more than capable of your calculations, and if it's not, which doubt, you can run your C# code in SQL Server.

Comment: @Stephanie Page,  Right now i am doing everything in database. simple calculation is current price of a particular stock is > a value (feeded by user). I want to put these conditions in memory because application need to perform actions based on these condition. At present i, write the records to the database, some trigger perform the condition checking task store result to a different table and application keep querying that table for change. That delayed the output. offcouse there are complex conditions which need to be kept in database.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is reading, but title implies writing?

When reading, consider (bit don't blindly use) temporary tables to cache data if you're going to do some processing. However, by simple calculations I assume aggregates live AVG, MAX etc?

It would generally be inane to drag data around, cache it in the client and aggregate it there.

If batch uploads:

- SQLBulkCopy or similar to a staging table
- Single write from staging to final table with

If single upload, just insert it

A million rows a day is a rounding error for what SQL Server ('Orable, MySQL, DB2 etc) is capable of

Example: [35k transaction (not rows) per second](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/12/12/10-lessons-from-35k-tps.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Simple conditions is just checking >,<,= etc. for calculating AVG,MAX,MIN.... I am still using stored proc. 

The other complex calculations keep SQL server under presure. We have UI to add conditions. 

There are plenty of dynamic sql statement, having Group by clause, need to be executed every 2 seconds. 

It keeps Server very busy and sometime CPU uses gone to 100%. 
We remove some conditions at those time.

Now i am trying to move some of the conditions to my application where i directly check it against recieved data.